# Change Visibilty of imageviews in alertdialog-Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to build an custom alertdialog in which there are 3 `ImageViews` .I want to hide and show these `ImageViews` dynamically.Here is my showroute() in HomeActivity class in which i'm creating the custom dialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.routedialog, null));
    alertDialog.setTitle("Home Activity");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Route Details</b>"));
    ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.routedialog, null);
    iv1=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv2=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    iv3=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv3);


    iv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    iv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    iv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll).invalidate();
```

and here is my routedialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ivred" />
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ivblue" />
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ivgreen" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want these `ImageViews` to be hidden when the dialog manager pops up and has to be made visible dynamically after checking certain conditions.Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inflating the layout again

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
 View convertView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.routedialog, null);
 alertDialog.setView(convertView);
```

Now initialize views and set the visibility for the views. Also check whether you want `GONE` or `INVISIBLE` @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility depending on your need

Also i do not see anywhere `iv4,iv5,iv6,iv7,iv8` in your custom dialog layout.

This

```
   iv4=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv4);
   iv5=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv5);
   iv6=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv6);
   iv7=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv7);
   iv8=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv8);
```

will give `NullPointerException`.

Edit :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.routedialog, null);
        alertDialog.setView(convertView);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Home Activity");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Route Details</b>"));
        ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3;
        iv1=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        iv2=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv2);
        iv3=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv3);
        iv1.setVisibility(View.GONE); // GONE oR INVISIBLE according to what you want
        iv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        iv3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        alertDialog.show();
```

Snap when imageview is visible

[image]

Comment: Thanks for ur answer..But i want the image views to be invisible when the dialog window pops up and should be made visible after checknig some condition..

Comment: @Lal set the visibility to `INVISIBLE`. or in xml for the views `andorid:visibility="INVISIBLE"`. Then on condition make it visible